# Connect liferay 7.3 (Docker container) with mysql DB(not in container)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, vue.js, liferay

I have a docker file for running liferay application and its perfectly running inside container. I want to communicate with Mysql DB. Here one condition is DB should not be inside a container.
Here i changed settings in "portal-ext.properties" file. But always showing error like connection refused.
And application is not running.

Comment: Could you provide more details (dockerfile, url to connect on db, etc...)